# Task that is making me crazy

Tags: java, external

Been working on this homework task for quite a while now and cant seem to get the answer, some feedback on my code would be appreciated. I have an input text file that has the following in it

```
 Min: 1,2,3,5,6
 Max: 1,2,3,5,6
 Avg: 1,2,3,5,6
 P90: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
 Sum: 1,2,3,5,6
 P70: 1,2,3
```

my task is to read the input text file and create an output text file that reads as follows:

```
The min of [1,2,3,5,6] is 1.
The max of [1,2,3,5,6] is 6.
The avg of [1,2,3,5,6] is 3.4.
The 90th percentile of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is 9.
The sum of [1,2,3,5,6] is 17.
The 70th percentile of [1,2,3] is 2.
```

So far I am just trying the min max and avg, I can read the file and I can output what I read in. I dont know how to find min max avg etc and output those values. seems to be because my input is a string and I need to only read the int values. No matter what I do it runs but will not print anything to the external text file.

```
public class ExternalData {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Dropbox\\Kevin Carter-8042\\Intro to Soft Eng\\Task 12\\input.txt");
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Dropbox\\Kevin Carter-8042\\Intro to Soft Eng\\Task 12\\outputTest.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo));

    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(strLine);

        String[] arr = strLine.split("");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        String[] nos = arr[4].split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nos));

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nos.length; i++) {
            int no = Integer.parseInt(nos[i]);
            set.add(no);
        }
        TreeSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(set);

        switch (arr[0]) {

            case "Min:":
                String msg1 = "The Min of [" + arr[2] + "] is " + (Integer) sortedSet.first();
                System.out.println(msg1);
                bw.write(msg1);
                bw.newLine();

                break;

            case "Max:":
                String msg2 = "The Max of [" + arr[0] + "] is " + (Integer) sortedSet.last();
                System.out.println(msg2);
                bw.write(msg2);
                bw.newLine();
                break;

            case "Avg:":
                Object[] noarray = sortedSet.toArray();
                int noarraysize = noarray.length - 1;
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= noarraysize; i++) {

                    int no = Integer.valueOf(noarray[i].toString());
                    sum = sum + no;
                    if (i == noarraysize) {
                        String msg3 = "The Avg of [" + arr[0] + "] is  " + (double) sum / noarray.length;
                        System.out.println(msg3);
                        bw.write(msg3);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "Sum:":
                Object[] noarray1 = sortedSet.toArray();
                int noarraysize1 = noarray1.length - 1;
                int sum1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= noarraysize1; i++) {
                    int no = Integer.valueOf(noarray1[i].toString());
                    sum1 = sum1 + no;
                    if (i == noarraysize1) {
                        String msg4 = "The Sum of [" + arr[0] + "] is  " + sum1;
                        System.out.println(msg4);
                        bw.write(msg4);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}
}
```

Comment: "`String[] arr = strLine.split("");`" what is in `arr[0]` after this?

Comment: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You already inserted a lot of `System.out.println()` statements. Do they show the values you expected? Maybe you want to add your program's output to your question, so we can better help you.

Comment: Your question's text and your code don't match. You already have some promising attempts on converting the input string to numbers, computing min, max, sum etc. in your code. Is your text simply out of sync with your state of coding or did you copy some code you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

`split("")` is unwieldy, and attempts to use the results of it are problematic.  To simplify this problem, first split the input by a colon which will help determine the operation and the list of integers (nos)

```
    String[] resultOfColanSplit = strLine.split(":");
    String operation = resultOfColanSplit [0];
    String[] nos = resultOfColanSplit [1].split(",");
```

Now you will have the values you expected (your nos[] array is not correct based on your original logic).

Then in your switch statement, use 'operation' instead of arr[0], and remove the ":" (which is no longer part of the operation string).

I found a further problem related to parsing the int, and found replacing blanks helped:

```
int no = Integer.parseInt(nos[i].replaceAll(" ", ""));
```